# What exactly is the chaining rules in Porco in the Sky

Tags: psn, everyday-shooter

I know that chaining is the key to scoring the big points and not getting overwhelmed by numbers in *Riff: Everyday Shooter*. However I'm having trouble on some of the levels working out exactly how to chain efficiently.

On "Porco in the Sky" I notice the little cubes which gain a halo when shot and I see some chains start to appear. Should I be staying within the halo or does it not matter where I shoot from once I activate the cube? Does anything help be destroy the floating suns faster other than staying still and concentrating my fire? It's tricky as the suns explode their fighters out on a fairly regular basis.